# Getting rid of punctuations in Strings

Tags: java, string, char, substring

I know that there are a few shorthand ways to go about this in Java, such as

```js
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
```

but I've been instructed to create a method that would get rid of punctuations without using such kinds of ~1 line shortcuts.

This is what I've attempted so far—

```js
      private String removePunctuation( String s )
      {
         //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
         String resultString = ""; 
         String punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()~?,.:;\"'";
         for(int i = 0; i<s.length()-1; i++)
         {
            String sub = s.substring(i, i+1);
            if(punctuations.indexOf(sub) == -1) 
            {
               //sb.deleteCharAt(i); 
               resultString += s.substring(i, i+1); 
            }
         }
         //String resultString = sb.toString(); 
         return resultString; 
      }
```

However, while it does run without "errors", it turns out that my strings are not changed and still contain punctuations within them. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Share the input strings for which it is not working

Comment: The only error I notice is the last character in `s` is not returned; other than that it does remove punctuation.  How are you verifying the results?  To fix the last character get rid of the `-1` in the for loop - `substring` is exclusive so it can be length.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem but your use of successive `substring` is incorrect (and unnecessary). Instead, create an empty `StringBuilder` and iterate each index of your input `String`. Take the character at that index and then check that it is not present in your set of `punctuations`. Assuming it isn't, append it to the `StringBuilder`. When done with iteration, return the `StringBuilder` as a `String`. Like,

```
private String removePunctuation(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()~?,.:;\"'";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (punctuations.indexOf(ch) < 0) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers undoubtedly will improve on your approach but your code works other than last character - how are you verifying results? This displays `hello world`.  To fix the last character just modify your for loop - `substring` is exclusive.

**This is your code with only the for loop changed** - and it works so post how you are verifying your results.

```
  public class HelloWorld
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String s = removePunctuation("^^^&*())))!!!?%%!!?~~..he;;':llo!! '''@#$wo...;\"rld");
      System.out.println(s);
    }

  private static String removePunctuation( String s )
        {
           //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
           String resultString = ""; 
           String punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()~?,.:;\"'";
           for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
           {
              String sub = s.substring(i, i+1);
              if(punctuations.indexOf(sub) == -1) 
              {
                 //sb.deleteCharAt(i); 
                 resultString += s.substring(i, i+1); 
              }
           }
           //String resultString = sb.toString(); 
           return resultString; 
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach to the problem.
Note: I did not test it fully, so don't just copy and paste.

```
private String removePunctuation( String s )
      {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
         String punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()~?,.:;\"'";
         for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
         {
            if(punctuations.contains(String.valueOf(sb.charAt(i)))) 
            {
               sb.deleteCharAt(i);
               i--; //Go back 1 index since we just deleted one
            }
         }
         String resultString = sb.toString(); 
         return resultString; 
      }
```